# django rest framework know if view is class or function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was implementing my custom permission where I had to check if view is `function` or `class`.

I have done the following

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):

        print("request ===", view, inspect.isfunction(view), inspect.isclass(view))
```

Here both `inspect.isfunction(view), inspect.isclass(view)` gives me false.

How can I determine if a view is functin or class ??

Comment: that's a weird permission condition  Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of such a permission condition?

Comment: @JPG .. wanted to make it generic and its working like charm.. `view.func.cls` this gave me what I wanted.. no issues

Answer (score -1):

The view argument of `has_permission` will always be a function.

Either what i believe you call a function, either a class method (so a function associated with an object).

```py
class YourClassName(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    def get(self, request):
        # the method get, not the class, is passed to your permission check.
```

**Edit**:

As ValidName said in the comments, Django started handling requests with function based view only. Since then, they have introduced class based view which are basically translated into functions and thus considered as such behind the scenes.

Comment: Worth mentioning that at first django had only function based views, so when they introduced class based views they made them back compatible with function based, by code, which transforms class base view into function. So in some places class based view can be represented as function due to this transformation.